# Audio Unit Bandpass Filter iOS

Tags: ios, bandwidth, audiounit

I'm developing a Bandpass Filter for iOS and the filter needs two parameters (center frequency and bandwidth). The problem basically is that bandwidth is in Cents (range 100-1200) instead of Hz. I've tried to find a way to convert from Cents to Hz but apparently there is no way. I also tried this [link](http://www.sengpielaudio.com/calculator-centsratio.htm) but the range of bandwidth that I'm using doesn't fit.

So, does anyone know something about this? Is there another way to implement a bandpass filter using audio units?

Thanks for the help. Any explanation would be really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation can be found in `AudioUnitProperties.h` :

`if f is freq in hertz then absoluteCents = 1200 * log2(f / 440) + 6900`